# Expectation of stochastic process continuous in starting point.

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, continuity, brownian-motion, expected-value

Let $(B_t)$ be a Brownian motion started in $x$ and $f_1,\dots,f_n$ be $\mathbb{R}$-valued continuous bounded functions. Consider the map $x \mapsto \mathbb{E}^x \big( f_1(B_{t_1}) \cdots f_n(B_{t_n}) \big)$.

Is it true that this map is continuous?

My answer: Yes, write $$\mathbb{E} \big( f_1(B_{t_1}+x) \cdots f_n(B_{t_n}+x) \big).$$ Since all $f_i$ are bounded I can use dominated convergence to pull in the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow y}$ and by the continuity of all $f_i$ the claim follows.

Is this correct? Because then this statement would be completely independent of Brownian motion and would hold for every stochastic process.

Comment: Can anybody help? Should be a standard question but I am not sure..

Comment: yes it has nothing to do with the Brownian motion

Comment: @Ryan In some sense it **does** have to do with Brownian motion. For general Markov processes, $E^x(f(X_t)) = Ef(x+X_t)$ fails to hold (where $E=E^0$).

Comment: @saz Thanks for the comment! In our course on stochastic processes, we defined in case of a Brownian motion $B_t$, $P^x$ to be the probability measure (path measure) of the process $B_t +x$. Is it for a general Markov process defined in another way?

Comment: @nabla Yes, they are defined differently. Pretty sure you will learn about this lateron in your course...